# Representing a Kibana query in a REST, curl form

Tags: rest, http, curl, elasticsearch, kibana

I have a [Kibana server](https://wikitech.wikimedia.org/wiki/Logstash#Kibana) in a classic [ELK](https://www.elastic.co/webinars/elk-stack-devops-environment) configuration, querying an [Elasticsearch](https://wikitech.wikimedia.org/wiki/Logstash#Elasticsearch) instance.

I use the Kibana console to execute sophisticated queries on elasticsearch. I would like to use some of these queries in the command linem using cURL or any other http tool.

**How can I convert a Kibana search into a [direct, cURL-like REST call to elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html)?**

Answer (score 32, accepted):

At the bottom of your visualization, there is a small caret you can click in order to view more details about the underlying query:

[image: View more info]

Then you can click on the "Request" button in order to view the underlying query, which you can copy/paste and do whatever suits you with it.

[image]

**UPDATE**

Then you can copy/paste the query from the "Request" textarea and simply paste it in a curl like this:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/_search -d '{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "analyze_wildcard": true,
          "query": "blablabla AND blablabla"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "@timestamp": {
                  "gte": 1439762400000,
                  "lte": 1439848799999
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": []
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "pre_tags": [
      "@kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
      "@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "fields": {
      "*": {}
    }
  },
  "size": 420,
  "sort": {
    "@timestamp": "desc"
  },
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "interval": "30m",
        "pre_zone": "+02:00",
        "pre_zone_adjust_large_interval": true,
        "min_doc_count": 0,
        "extended_bounds": {
          "min": 1439762400000,
          "max": 1439848799999
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "fields": [
    "*",
    "_source"
  ],
  "script_fields": {},
  "fielddata_fields": [
    "@timestamp"
  ]
}'
```

You may need to tweak a few stuff (like pre/post highlight tags, etc)

Comment: // , Is the relevant documentation here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search.html

Comment: It's not clear to me what values to put into `your_index` and `your_type`

Comment: @RoyTruelove Whatever index/type you want to query

Comment: But, where does one find the index/type to put in 'your_index' and 'your_type' ?

Comment: @David feel free to ask another question related to your case referencing this one.

Comment: where is it in the UI, because I can't find

Comment: @HahaTTpro in the latest versions, it's located in the "Inspect" menu.

Answer (score 17):

In case you are online using a Chrome browser you can go to your Kibana dashboard, open the developer console and write your query while having the `Network` tab open in the developer console. When you search for your query in the Kibana dashboard you will see the request appear in the developer console. There you can "right click" and select `Copy as cURL`, which will copy the curl command to your clipboard. Note that credentials of your basic auth may be copied as well. So be careful where you paste it.

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to query Elastic Search using lucene queries (same syntax Kibana uses) using the ES search API `query_string` queries:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

Taken from one of the doc example, you would query ES using something like this:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "default_field" : "content",
            "query" : "this AND that OR thus"
        }
    }
}
```