# how could I inspect what the query sent to the elasticsearch from kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

The Kibana is an awesome visualization tool,

I want to know what the queries does the elasticsearch recevices under the hood.

How could I know what the queries that the elasticsearch got.
Thanks

Comment: This answer might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32052507/representing-a-kibana-query-in-a-rest-curl-form/32052780#32052780

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each visualization has a button below it, in the shape of an arrow pointing up. Clicking on it will replace the vizualization with a table, which has a bunch on tabs on the top. Clicking on the second tab from the left will show the exact query that was made to elasticsearch